# Loading data while scrolling down VS pagination

Tags: jquery, user-interface

I am designing a website and in the first page I may have lots of datas loaded.I am thinking about two ways.

> First way is to paging them like lots of the websites(For example this
>   website).
>
> And the second is load them while scrolling down like facebook.

I want to know your viewpoints about that.I want to know:

> Which one is more optimize or even is there any diffrence.
>
> Which one is more user friendly.
>
> And which one do you prefer yourself as a simple user and a web
>   developer.

It was hard for me to choice and I want to give help from you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. There is a very small performance benefit doing "infinite scroll" in
   that you are only requesting the data from the server and not doing
   a full page request.
2. I think infinite scroll is more user friendly since once the user
   reaches the bottom of the page you'll show them the next results
   instead of a pager that they have to click on to request more
   results.
3. I prefer infinite scroll